# Escape without using mysql escape string

Tags: php, mysql, yii

How do I escape data being inserted into a MySQL table without using an SQL escape string to protect against SQL injection?

I'm using Yii framework which uses PDO and does not support multiple queries. I need to run multiple insert queries and need to escape the values being inserted.

`Yii::app()->quoteValue` does not work because it places quotes `""` around the input being inserted into mysql. Is there a PHP function I can use to protect against SQL injections?

Comment: If you have your values as parameters in prepared statements, chances are you are already safe

Comment: If you are using PDO, you should be using prepared statements which do not require additional escaping so long as you use placeholders correctly and don't concatenate in strings.

Comment: I think his problem is that he needs to build a multiple-insert query and his framework (which is using PDO) does not support the multiple-insert query.

Comment: `does not work because it places quotes...` that sounds like it's already being escaped.

Comment: `I need to run multiple insert queries and need to escape the values being inserted.` what library do you want to use for this then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add slashes with

```
$string = addslashes($string);
```

However, it's recommended you try and use the proper mysql methods instead so I wouldn't count on this being a perfect replacement.

Comment: You will then need to run `stripcslashes($variable)` when getting the query back from the database if you use the above approach.

Comment: This is not safe, addslashes is not a proper way to sanitize database input.

Comment: Hence my comment saying this isn't recommended :)

Comment: No comments needed. Just don't post bad answers ;)